# UDF to return Y value from given X value using 5th Polynomial

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, polynomials

I have a range on several sheets in the same workbook, with 35 off "X" values in a column and need to return "Y" values corresponding to a customized 5th Polynomial Curve / Function on a fixed sheet called "DB" with supporting "x" values on C37:C76 and "y" values on D37:D76 for the aforementioned curve.

Essentially a graphical VLOOKUP function instead of a table with 1000s of rows.

As a once-off calculation, the normal calculation method works 100% but it becomes an issue if you need to calculate Y for several values of X over several sheets. I thought a UDF would work, but I'm at a loss of how to actually do it. I tried a few code variations and cleaned it up for this post as a starting point.

Any help to make this UDF work would be greatly appreciated.

```
Function ADJ(X As Single) As Single

'X = FUNCTION INPUT VALUE
'Y = RESULT = ADJ = C5*X^5 + C4*X^4 + C3*X^3 + C2*X^2 + C1*X^1 + A
        
        C1 = Sheets(11).Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(R37C3:R76C3, R37C4:R76C4^{1,2,3,4,5}), 1, 5)")
        C2 = Sheets(11).Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(R37C3:R76C3, R37C4:R76C4^{1,2,3,4,5}), 1, 4)")
        C3 = Sheets(11).Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(R37C3:R76C3, R37C4:R76C4^{1,2,3,4,5}), 1, 3)")
        C4 = Sheets(11).Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(R37C3:R76C3, R37C4:R76C4^{1,2,3,4,5}), 1, 2)")
        C5 = Sheets(11).Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(R37C3:R76C3, R37C4:R76C4^{1,2,3,4,5}), 1, 1)")
         A = Sheets(11).Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(R37C3:R76C3, R37C4:R76C4^{1,2,3,4,5}), 1, 6)")
       ADJ = C5 * X ^ 5 + C4 * X ^ 4 + C3 * X ^ 3 + C2 * X ^ 2 + C1 * X ^ 1 + A
         
End Function
```

Running it as a Sub:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ADJ1()

Dim ADJ As Variant
Dim X As Variant
Dim A As Variant
Dim C1 As Variant
Dim C2 As Variant
Dim C3 As Variant
Dim C4 As Variant
Dim C5 As Variant

X = 3

         C1 = Sheets(11).Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(D37:D76, C37:C76^{1,2,3,4,5}), 1, 5)")
         C2 = Sheets(11).Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(D37:D76, C37:C76^{1,2,3,4,5}), 1, 4)")
         C3 = Sheets(11).Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(D37:D76, C37:C76^{1,2,3,4,5}), 1, 3)")
         C4 = Sheets(11).Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(D37:D76, C37:C76^{1,2,3,4,5}), 1, 2)")
         C5 = Sheets(11).Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(D37:D76, C37:C76^{1,2,3,4,5}), 1, 1)")
          A = Sheets(11).Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(D37:D76, C37:C76^{1,2,3,4,5}), 1, 6)")
       
       'ADJ = C5 * X ^ 5 + C4 * X ^ 4 + C3 * X ^ 3 + C2 * X ^ 2 + C1 * X ^ 1 + A
       
       ADJ = X ^ 5 + X ^ 4 + X ^ 3 + X ^ 2 + X ^ 1
       MsgBox ADJ
       
       
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to evaluate a worksheet formula then you need to use the `Worksheet.Evaluate` method.  Eg `C1 = mySheet.Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(R37C3:R76C3, R37C4:R76C4^{1,2,3,4,5}), 1, 5)")` And move the `ADJ = ...` line to after the inputs to that line have been assigned.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I updated the code (shown above), but get a #Value! error

Comment: Run your function from a Sub so you can see where the problem is. Do you actually have a worksheet with a codename of "mySheet" ?

Comment: I gave X a random value, and without any of the C1 through A values, it works, i.e. a message box pops up with the calculated ADJ value. As soon as I add A for example I get a type mismatch error. I'm guessing that means the A calculation returns an error .. perhaps? Could it be that the ```Sheets(11).Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(D37:D76, C37:C76^{1,2,3,4,5}), 1, 6)")``` formatting is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution and opinion. Still I am not sure that the opinion is quite correct.
Opinion: I would never use UDF with reference to a range. The Range you are working with must be an argument of the function.
See this solution:

```
Public Function ADJ(X As Range, Y As Range, xvalue As Double) As Double
    Dim pol As Variant
    Dim arrPolNth As Variant
    Dim n As Integer
    n = 5
    arrPolNth = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    pol = Application.LinEst(Y, Application.Power(X, arrPolNth))
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(pol) To UBound(pol)
        ADJ = ADJ + Application.Power(xvalue, n - i + 1) * pol(i)
    Next i
End Function
```

It is not the nicest because the order of the polynomial should be also a parameter.

Comment: Thanks Viktor. Interesting solution. I thought of using a Range because then I can plot the curve and fine-tune it to suit in one central place. If I understand you correctly, the range should then be part of the VBA code, and not located on a sheet? If so, where would I define the values of X and Y (40 values each)?

Comment: Actually if your function is called from the worksheet, it is not a good practice to have direct communication with range object. If you would like to have an array (range) instead of a single value, the function shall have an input range and can return the array of the calculated estimates. If you would be happy with this solution I can modify the code for you.

Comment: Ahh, now I see what you did there. I missed the fact that the range is defined in the UDF, i.e. ```=ADJ(D37:D76,C37:C76,H51)``` (even though you said so) and now it works perfectly just as you proposed above! Thank you very much Viktor!